# AngularJs deferred is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I check with every request if the user is authorized. This is my factory:

```
(function()
{
    angular.module('employeeApp').factory('authenticationFactory', authenticationFactory);

    function authenticationFactory($cookieStore,$cookies,requestFactory,$location,GLOBALS,constants,$q)
    {
        var factory = {};

        factory.validateUser = function()
        {
            var vm = this;
            vm.deferred = $q.defer();

            if($location.path() != '/')
            {
                var api_token = factory.getToken();

                factory.isValidToken(api_token).then(function(response) {
                    if (response.status != 200) {
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                    data = {"api_token": api_token};
                    return requestFactory.post(GLOBALS.url + 'show/employee/' + $cookies.get('employeeid'), data)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            vm.deferred.resolve(response.data);
                            console.log(vm.deferred);
                            return vm.deferred.promise;
                        }, function(response) {
                            vm.deferred.reject(response);
                            return vm.deferred.promise;
                        });
                });
            }
        }
        return factory;
    }
})()
```

If I console.log `vm.deferred` I see an object.

But if I `console.log(authenticationFactory.validateUser());` in my `routes` file I see `empty` in my console?

```
(function () {

angular.module('employeeApp').config(routeModule).run(run);

routeModule.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

function routeModule($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../views/login.html',
        controller: 'authenticationController',
        controllerAs: 'authenticationCtrl'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '../views/index.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        controllerAs: 'homeCtrl',
        resolve: {
            message: function(authenticationFactory){
                return authenticationFactory.validateUser();
            }
        }
    })
    .when('/werknemer/:id', {
        templateUrl: '../views/employee/employee.html',
        controller: 'employeeController',
        controllerAs: 'employeeCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}


function run(authenticationFactory)
{
    console.log(authenticationFactory.validateUser());
}
})();
```

Looking for hours now please some help!

Answer (score 0):

From your first example, you're misunderstanding how Angular's `$http` service works. `$http.post` returns a *promise*, something that will be resolved some time in the future. Just calling `authenticationFactory.validateUser()` like you're doing is returning the unresolved promise.

It looks like your `authenticationFactory` is already `return`ing a promise object, so to call it, try doing it like this:

```
function run(authenticationFactory)
{
    authenticationFactory.validateUser().then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Take a look at the [docs for Angular's promise service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for a good idea of how to use the promises.

Also, it looks to me from your second example like you're misunderstanding how Angular's dependency injection works.

In your second example, the `authenticationFactory` is never being injected, so it ends up being undefined.

Also bear in mind that during the `config` phase of a module, only `providers` can be injected, so you will be unable to inject the `authenticationFactory` in your `config` function. (Unless you write and then inject an `authenticationFactoryProvider`

I'd look at rewriting the code from your second example to work similar to this. Notice that I'm using the [inline array dependency annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) which according to the docs is the preferred method. Your method using `$inject` explicitly would work, but it's easier to go wrong. (And slightly less clear to see what's being injected)

Disclaimer: untested.

```
(function () {

var employeeAppModule = angular.module('employeeApp');

employeeAppModule.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: '../views/login.html',
            controller: 'authenticationController',
            controllerAs: 'authenticationCtrl'
        })
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: '../views/index.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/werknemer/:id', {
            templateUrl: '../views/employee/employee.html',
            controller: 'employeeController',
            controllerAs: 'employeeCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
]);

employeeAppModule.run([
    'authenticationFactory',
    function(authenticationFactory) {
        console.log(authenticationFactory.validateUser());
    }
]);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But like this it's also not working. When I say in my factory return 'test'; The console.log in my routesfile is 'test'. So the factory is reached. Very very frustrating -_-.

Comment: it's still undefined. It looks like the response is received after the console.log could that be possible?